# What do you call the fletching of an arrow in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, sustantivos

I'm talking about the feather part of an arrow that helps stabilise it in flight. I tried Google translate and it's not returning anything.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are called "Plumas" o [remeras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remeras_(flecha)).

[See here](http://learningarcherywithjrs.blogspot.com/2013/10/partes-de-la-flecha.html)

This could be easily verified if you search ["partes de la flecha"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_esCO836CO836&q=partes%20de%20la%20flecha&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgl-v8z-vgAhUIjlkKHfxFDLAQBQgrKAA&biw=1745&bih=886)

The most common result from the search is "plumas" however [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flecha) show the "remeras" result in a picture but also refers to them as " plumas" in the text.

So I think "plumas" is without doubts the most used term.

[image: taken from https://mtpisgahadventurerclub.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/8/9/13890099/partes_de_una_flecha-maestro.pdf]
<sub>image taken from https://mtpisgahadventurerclub.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/8/9/13890099/partes_de_una_flecha-maestro.pdf</sub>

Comment: That's interesting considering remeras could also mean T-shirt in some Latin american countries.

Comment: @Morgan That is correct. "Remera" comes from the Spanish verb for "to row" (remar) as in a boat. Perhaps T-shirts started as sporting cloths used to row (sail) in some places, but I'll let that for someone from Argentina. I only saw that name on the wikipedia page. All others refer to the fletchings as _plumas_.